# Use = instead of <- for assignment when styling R code with styler

Tags: r, tidyverse, assignment-operator

I love the package but I was wondering how I could change one rule from the tidyverse style: I'd like to keep "=" instead of "<-" for assignment.

I've read that note: http://styler.r-lib.org/articles/customizing_styler.html#implementation-details

But I still don't get how to simply change that rule.
I've tried the very naive:

```
library(styler)

force_assignment_op  <- function (pd) 
  {
    to_replace <- pd$token == "LEFT_ASSIGN"
    pd$token[to_replace] <- "EQ_ASSIGN"
    pd$text[to_replace] <- "="
    pd
 }


tidyverse_style()$token$force_assignment_op = force_assignment_op
```

But get the following error:

```
Error in tidyverse_style()$token$force_assignment_op = 
force_assignment_op : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

I would like to modify it in a way that I can simply run the styler addin afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `tidyverse_style()$token` is a list, not an environment, so you can't modify it.  (Well, you can modify it, but you're modifying a copy, not the original.)

You need to write your own function to replace the `tidyverse_style` function, and use it instead.  For example, assuming you keep your `force_assignment_op` function:

```
LaSy_style <- function(...) {
  ts <- tidyverse_style(...)
  ts$token$force_assignment_op <- force_assignment_op
  ts
}
```

Then

```
style_text(c("ab <- 3", "a  <-3"), strict = FALSE, style = LaSy_style)
```

(one of the examples from `?tidyverse_style`) will print

```
ab = 3
a  = 3
```

(This is ugly, the original `tidyverse_style` is better, but I won't stop you.)

Comment: Thanks a ton! This works. 

Now... do you (or anyone?) know how I can tell the styler addin to use LaSy_style instead of tidyverse_style?

(hehe... I know... it's "ugly" but I'm lazy ;))

Comment: I think it hardcodes `tidyverse_style`, so you'll either need to write your own addin (which isn't hard, see http://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/), or convince the `styler` authors to make it configurable.

Comment: I recently saw that there is a [fork](https://github.com/miraisolutions/styler) that implements custom style guide fro addins. Will at some point try to merge back into upstream, haven't tried. You can use the remotes package to install it.

Comment: As of styler 1.1.1, you can now select the style guide with the Addin. See https://github.com/r-lib/styler/releases/tag/v1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to derive such a style from tidyverse_style. (As stated in earlier answer) Below example is the minimal needed code, which is only about 20 lines give and take. [This code example was copied from here.](https://github.com/pola-rs/r-polars/blob/ffe30500954ab54a6386ef8923b69d5594ac4cd8/dev/styler_utils.R#L5) Modifying styler one rule can have some idiosyncratic side-effects, which needs a bit more code to handle. But with a little fiddling it can work out fine.

```
rpolars_style = function() {
  # derive from tidyverse
  transformers = styler::tidyverse_style()
  transformers$style_guide_name = "rpolars_style"
  transformers$style_guide_version = "0.1.1"

  # reverse tranformer to make <- into =
  transformers$token$force_assignment_op = function(pd) {
    to_replace = pd$token == "LEFT_ASSIGN"

    # pretect against changing globalAssign operator, which does not have a unique defined token.
    if (any(to_replace)) {
      to_replace = to_replace & pd$text != "<<-"
    }

    pd$token[to_replace] = "EQ_ASSIGN"
    pd$text[to_replace] = "="
    pd
  }

  # Specify which tokens must be absent for a transformer to be dropped
  # https://styler.r-lib.org/reference/specify_transformers_drop.html?q=transformers%20_%20drop
  transformers$transformers_drop$token$force_assignment_op = "LEFT_ASSIGN"

  transformers
}

#use example
styler::style_dir(path = ".", style = rpolars_style())
```